# Next.js - You can not use getInitialProps with getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

So I have a dynamic route `/post/[slug]` and want to add the package `next-i18next`. I am wrapping each page in a HOC which handles all my GraphQL stuff (`next-apollo`). This HOC uses `getInitialProps`, and `next-i18next` wants `getStaticProps` (SSG) or `getServerSideProps` (SSR). However, Next doesn't allow for `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` to be used with `getInitialProps`.

Is there a workaround this? Can I just change the source code of the `next-apollo` to be SSR or SSG instead or static?

A few links:

- [My component (`/post/[slug]`)](https://github.com/herbievine/blog/blob/main/pages/post/%5Bslug%5D.tsx#L59-L63)
- [Apollo HOC](https://github.com/herbievine/blog/blob/main/lib/withApollo.ts)
- [`next-i18next`](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next#serversidetranslations)
- [`next-apollo`](https://github.com/adamsoffer/next-apollo/blob/master/src/withApollo.tsx#L138-L208)

Comment: No I'm using version 10.2.0

Comment: Well, I know that. But the apollo HOC I'm using uses `getInitialProps`, so is there a workaround?

Comment: Oh, I see now, sorry. I would fork next-apollo and try just switching out getInitialProps with getStaticProps. May throw some oddness, but shouldn't take too much to get it working. If you get it working may as well post a pull-request as well.

Comment: Ok ty will have a go

Comment: `next-apollo` hasn't been updated in a while - I'd recommend following the implementation from the [`with-apollo`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo) official example.